# how to measure he similarity between two 2D complex fields in matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, statistics

I have a matrix operation `Y=B*A*X;` ; where `A=exp(1i.*pi*rand(50,50)); B=transpose(A);`

X is the input which is random

```
X=exp(1i.*pi*rand(50,50));
```

so I have Y calculated.

Now I find another Y say Y1 for another `X1=exp(1i.*pi*rand(50,50));` Y and Y1 are complex outputs. How can I measure the similarity between these fileds ?

Can someone please help. I have tried

`rsme=sqrt(mean(abs(Y1(:))-abs(Y(:)).^2);` But I guess it is a wrong measure ?

Comment: define similarity

Comment: I want to measure how much similar pixel by pixel Y1 is with Y

Comment: I know which 2 you need to compare.  Define, mathemathically, similarity

Comment: Hi Ander
Suppose I have two speckle intensities and I want to know what is the error between two intensities. Which method can I use? Will this rms error method help me ?

Answer (score 0):

The mean-squared error (MSE) is a common similarity estimation technique:

```
MSE=mean((abs(Y(:))-abs(Y1(:))).^2)
```

There is a build function in matlab called `immse` that gives the same result:

```
MSE=immse(Y,Y1)
```

The Structural Similarity Index (SSIM) is also an available technique:

```
ssimval = ssim(Y,Y1)
```

where Y1 is the reference image.